# JBoss AS 7.x Binding IP / DNS to access server from internet / intranet

Tags: jboss7.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deploy an application over the internet with JBoss AS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9842197/how-to-deploy-an-application-over-the-internet-with-jboss-as-7)

I’m trying to access JBoss AS 7.1.1 Final version by specifying DNS / static IP.

As per the steps mentioned in this article, I followed the steps:

1. Modify `standalone.conf`

   added: `JAVA_OPTS=”$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.bind.address=172.xx.xxx.xx` and restarted the server. When JBoss starts I see the specified IP but I can’t access the server from browser [`http://172.xx.xxx.x:8080`]
2. I also modified `standalone.xml` – interface tag like or 0.0.0.0

   When JBoss starts I see the specified IP but I can’t access the server from browser [`http://172.xx.xxx.x:8080`]

Please let me know what am missing. Very critical.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to bind on a specific IP is to use the "-b" option from the command line. For example

```
$ ./standalone.sh -b 172.xx.xx.xx
```

For more information refer to the [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Command+line+parameters)

Comment: Declaring the runtime switch values is nice, but you can persist these changes with the Management Console or the Management CLI. Using the `<any-address/>` element... https://community.jboss.org/wiki/MultipleInstancesOfJBossAS7OnTheSameMachine